# PHP two Dimensional array in to file

Tags: php, arrays

Can you please tell me how I can save a two dimensional array in to a text file

if I have an array with unknown number of elements in its index value:

```
$two_darray[unknown][unknown];
```

Comment: is encoding it to a JSON an option?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, @Brad's and @Hilmi's answers are correct, but I'm not sure using only JSON is a good advice.

You can choose

**JSON**

write: `file_put_contents('someFile.json', json_encode($two_darray));`

read: `$two_darray = json_decode(file_get_contents('someFile.txt'));`

**XML**

Look [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1397036/how-to-convert-array-to-simplexml)

**Serialized data**

write: `file_put_contents('someFile.txt', serialize($two_darray));`

read: `$two_darray = unserialize(file_get_contents('someFile.txt'));`

**CSV** (to use with MS Excel or some DB)

```
$handler = fopen('someFile.csv', 'w+');
foreach ($two_darray as $one_darray) {
    fputcsv($handler, $one_darray);
}
```

read it with [fgetcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php)

and even **SQLite**

```
$db = new SQLiteDatabase('someFile.sqlite');
foreach ($two_darray as $one_darray) {
    $db->query("INSERT INTO `MyTable` VALUES (".implode(',', $one_darray).")");
}
```

read: `$two_darray = $db->sqlite_array_query("SELECT * FROM MyTable");`

EDIT **Binary** (for .zip or .tar.gz)

Try [pack()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pack.php)

Comment: thats a nice explanation. Can you please show us how you read the value back in to an array using JSON and Serialized methods

Answer (score 4):

You simply need to serialize this array.  You can wrap it in [`serialize()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) and output this to a file.  You can then use [`unserialize()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) later to decode it.

For portability, I recommend using JSON instead, with [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)/[`json_decode()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php).

```
file_put_contents('someFile.json', json_encode($yourArray));
```

Comment: @Orangepill, Excellent point.  One other thing I forgot to mention that might influence the decision... if you need native PHP types, you will need PHP's serialization.

Comment: and for non-native classes make sure you have definitions included or an autoloader in play prior to calling unserialize or you will end up with a bunch of incomplete class objects.

Answer (score 0):

You can [serialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) the array to a string and save it into the file, and when ever you want that array just by [unserializing](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) the file's content you'll have the array back

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$arr = array( array('aa', 'aa'), array('bb','bb') );
file_put_contents('/tmp/test',serialize($arr));
var_dump(unserialize(file_get_contents('/tmp/test')));
?>
```

You can also use json_encode/json_decode instead of serialize/deserialize as suggested by @Brad above